# How can I force Chrome to stop fetching the same images?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, caching

When the user hovers over a particular area of screen, I create a div, then set the background:

```
div= document.createElement('div');

if (yellowBg) {
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'../partHoverBgYellow.png\')';
}
else {
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'../partHoverBg.png\')';
}

parent.appendChild(div)
```

In Firefox and IE, the background image gets cached after it is fetched for the first time.

But in chrome, it appears that it is not cached. The result being that the div appears before its background is set every time.

I have checked using Fiddler, and the image is indeed fetched every time.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the background with css and only change the className in code. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrGxw/) shows an idea to do that. In the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools you'll see that the images, after initial load, are subsequently loaded from cache.

The code becomes as simple as: `div.className = yellowBG ? 'yellowBG' : '';`

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BBak/) the images are preloaded.

Comment: Thanks. This is a really good answer. Now the images are only ever fetched one time, not repeatedly. I think to award the bounty, I'd need a mechanism that somehow preloads the images before I hover.

Comment: Hi @Urbycoz, glad it works. I've forked the jsfiddle adding preloading of the necessary images. See the updated answer for a link.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/X8SkS/3/

If you do

```
var img=document.createElement('img');
var urls=["../partHoverBgYellow.png","../partHoverBg.png"];
img.src=urls[0];
img.src=urls[1];
```

when the document is loading, the browser will download the images, so when you do

```
div.style.display = 'block';
```

Chrome will have the images in the cache, and the `div` and its background will apper at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm afraid this doesn't seem to make any difference. Chrome always fetches each image afresh regardless of how many times it has fetched it before.

Comment: Although strangely it doesn't do this in your jsfiddle code. Could it be because I am on localhost?

Comment: Same happened to me. Opera/Firefox/Safari/IE8 are loading images one time only, not chrome, but in jsfiddle, Chrome is ok. Meaning jsfiddle server is presumely sending the 'one-year cache info' in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the headers sent from the server, include the following:

```
Cache-control: public; max-age=31536000
```

So your image gets cached for a year on the client-side. This is the way and semantics that must be implemented by each and every browser. See [the W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) for further clarification.

Also, it is important to note that this header will disable you to update the aforementioned image.

Comment: I don't have any control of these. Sorry.